# How to get rid of duplicate records from several datasets efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, unique

I have 5 different datasets and I want to get rid of the duplicates in every dataset.

One way of doing it would be to run the unique function on the datasets one by one. But this is very inefficient and time consuming. I tried the following code but it did not get rid of the duplicates.

#Load datasets

```
daily_activites <- read_csv("dailyActivity_merged.csv")
daily_steps <- read_csv("dailySteps_merged.csv")
daily_intensities <- read_csv("dailyIntensities_merged.csv")
daily_calories <- read_csv("dailyCalories_merged.csv")
sleep_day <- read_csv("sleepDay_merged.csv")
```

#variable containing the names of all the datasets

```
dataset_names <- c("daily_activities", "daily_steps", "daily_intensities", "daily_calories", "sleep_day")
```

#get rid of duplicates

```
for (i in 1:length(dataset_names)) {
  dataset_names[i] <- unique(dataset_names[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If my answer has solved your question, you could consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget(dataset_names)` to put all data frames you want into a list, apply `unique()` to each of them by `lapply()`, and overwrite data into your workspace by `list2env()`.

```r
list2env(lapply(mget(dataset_names), unique), .GlobalEnv)
```